# Use of indexes (indices?) on Informix DB

Tags: sql, database, indexing, informix

I have a table with 5 million+ records on an Informix database.

This isn't the actual table but will show the problem I'm having.

Table: sales
Columns: sale_id, sale_confirmed, vendor_id, purchaser_id
Indexes: idx1(sale_id), idx2(sale_confirmed), idx3(vendor_id), idx4(purchaser_id)

If I do a query like this:

```
select *  
from sales  
where sale_confirmed IS NULL  
or sale_confirmed = ''
```

then the query runs to completion in about 4 or 5 seconds.

If I do a query like this:

```
select *  
from sales  
where vendor_id = 12345 
or purchaser_id = 12345
```

then the query runs to completion in about 4 or 5 seconds.

However, if I run this query (a combination of the 2 previous queries):

```
select *  
from sales  
where (sale_confirmed IS NULL  
        or sale_confirmed = '' )
and (vendor_id = 12345 
       or purchaser_id = 12345)
```

then the query ran for 15 mins before I cancelled it.

The database doesn't seem to be smart enough to use the different indexes in tandem i.e. it doesn't seem to be able to use idx2 to find X number of rows AND use idx3 and idx4 within that X number of rows - is that right, I would have thought it would be smart enough to do this?

Is there a way of forcing the database to use idx3 and idx4 when processing the second part of the WHERE clause?

Any other solutions short of creating new indexes?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of IDS are you using?  Are your statistics sufficiently up to date?  Did you look at the query plans with SET EXPLAIN ON?

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a UNION where only two indices have to be chosen from in each part:

```
select *  
from sales  
where (sale_confirmed IS NULL  
        or sale_confirmed = '' )
and vendor_id = 12345


UNION

select *  
from sales  
where (sale_confirmed IS NULL  
        or sale_confirmed = '' )
and purchaser_id = 12345
```

And if Informix supports inline views, get the set of rows based on vendor/purchaser and then from that set exclude the unconfirmed sales.

```
select inlineview.*  from
(
select *  from sales  
where vendor_id = 12345 or purchaser_id = 12345
) as inlineview
where (sale_confirmed IS NULL or sale_confirmed = '')
```

Finally, I think you might want to drop the low-cardinality index on sale_confirmed.

P.S. I would normally not have a column in my database that allowed the empty string, NULL, and other values. I'd constrain the field probably to a BIT type if you have it, with 1 and 0, with 0 default.

Answer (score 1):

The index on 'sale_confirmed' is unlikely to be useful because the cardinality of 'sale_confirmed' seems to be low (NULL, yes, no?).  A better schema design would enforce NOT NULL on 'sale_confirmed' and a CHECK constraint would enforce 'Y' or 'N' and a default could give you 'N' unless you specified otherwise.  That would avoid having to do OR operations on 'sale_confirmed', which are messy.

The UNION technique suggested by [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312908/tim) is likely to be a decent workaround.